# Python replace || operator with CONCAT function using python

Tags: python, sql

I have an SQL query with the `||` operator and I want to rewrite the query using `concat()`. Can any one help in doing it because I have the query of `||` operator one inside the other?

```py
SQL_query="""select  TIME.CURRENT_YEAR  as  Year1,
     TIME.QUARTER_KEY  as  Quarter_key,
     (( TIME .MONTH_EN || N' ') || cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as Month__caption_,
                              (( TIMEQUARTER.QUARTER_EN || N' ') || cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as  Quarter__caption_
    from
        [GOSALESDW]. TIME   TIME ,
        [GOSALESDW]. TIMEQUARTER  TIMEQUARTER
    where
         ( TIME .QUARTER_KEY =  TIMEQUARTER.QUARTER_KEY) """
```

I want to replace the `||` concat operator with the `concat` function.

```sql
( TIME .MONTH_EN || N' ') || cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as  Month__caption_,
(( TIMEQUARTER.QUARTER_EN || N' ') || cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as  Quarter__caption_
```

The required output is:

```sql
CONCAT(CONCAT( TIME .MONTH_EN , N' ') , cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as  Month__caption_,
CONCAT(CONCAT( TIME_QUARTER.QUARTER_EN , N' ') , cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as  Quarter__caption_
```

Comment: I have an answer to this, it seems a fair question about using a technique to perform a tricky find-replace that alters structure rather than a simple in-place edit. In translating from one SQL dialect to another, this kind of problem arises fairly regularly. And while the poster hasn't provided any code showing what they might have attempted, it's a difficult one to approach if you only have find-replace in mind.

Comment: Can you explain how we can do or if you have a piece of code which will solve my question will be needed higy

Comment: I’ll post up the easier regex method on Monday. It relies on the pattern that appears to be in place here where each || operator is surrounded in parentheses. There’s one regex loop to extract all the ‘inner’ parentheses blocks and replace them with tokens. Then the blocks are converted from || to CONCAT style and re-substituted in place of the saved tokens.

Comment: Thank you, It will be very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we just do some setup, import the `re` library, and push the string into a variable..

```
import re

sql_string ="""select  TIME.CURRENT_YEAR  as  Year1,
     TIME.QUARTER_KEY  as  Quarter_key,
     (( TIME .MONTH_EN || N' ') || cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as Month__caption_,
                              (( TIMEQUARTER.QUARTER_EN || N' ') || cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as  Quarter__caption_
    from
        [GOSALESDW]. TIME   TIME ,
        [GOSALESDW]. TIMEQUARTER  TIMEQUARTER
    where
         ( TIME .QUARTER_KEY =  TIMEQUARTER.QUARTER_KEY)"""
```

Then define and store some regexes - the first one here finds instances of the double-pipe pattern, while the second one homes-in on the [most deeply nested pair of matching parentheses](https://regex101.com/r/fhqDDJ/1).

```
find_concat_operators=re.compile(r"\|\|")
find_innermost_brackets=re.compile(r"(\([^\(]*?\))")
```

Using the innermost_brackets regex, scan over the string and extracting the contents into replacable tokens, identifiable by the `__token_n__` pattern, used both in a list containing the replaced token values, and a matching dictionary containing the original text prior to replacement. After replacing the extracted parentheses' contents with a token place-holder, this process is iterated over a number of times until no parentheses remain.

```
split_contents=find_innermost_brackets.split(sql_string)

tokens={}
finished=False
tokenised_contents = []
t=-1
i=-1
while not finished:
    tokenised_contents=[]
    i+=1
    for e,s in enumerate(split_contents):

        if e%2==1:
            t+=1
            token_label="{{__token_{e}__}}".format(e=t)
            token_contents=s
            tokenised_contents.append((e,token_label, token_contents))
            tokens[token_label[1:-1]]=token_contents
        else:
            tokenised_contents.append((t,s, s))


    new_string = "".join([c[1] for c in tokenised_contents])
    split_contents = find_innermost_brackets.split(new_string)        
    if len(split_contents)==1:
        finished=True
```

At this stage, `tokenised_contents` contains elements of the original string with bracketed sections replaced with curly-bracketed placeholders with token-keys in place, such as `{__token_1__}`, `{__token_2__}` etc - and the `tokens` dictionary will contain a series of key-value pairs containing keys such as `__token_1__`, `__token_2__` and whose values will be the original bracketed statements associated with these keys.

Next, loop over the contents of the extracted parentheses (i.e. the values in the `tokens` dictionary) - looking for instances of `||` and using that as a means of splitting that text into a left-hand-side, right-hand-side set of pairs.

Once `lhs`, `rhs` pairs are known, these can be used to construct the CONCAT functions, which are replaced as the values in the tokens dictionary for the same dictionary keys.

```
for k,v in tokens.items():
    if (len(find_concat_operators.split(v))) > 1:
        lhs,rhs=find_concat_operators.split(v)
        print(find_concat_operators.split(v))
        tokens[k]="CONCAT({lhs},{rhs})".format(lhs=lhs[1:],rhs=rhs[:-1])
```

Finally, the transformed tokens are returned into their original locations by means of the python `format` operator, using the token dictionary as a set of replacement-parameters, and the original string reconstructed token by token until no further awaiting replacements remain.

```
while any(["{" in c[1] for c in tokenised_contents]):
    tokenised_contents=[(c[0], c[1].format(**tokens), c[2]) for c in tokenised_contents]
print("".join([c[1] for c in tokenised_contents]))
```

Which yields the following end-result.

```
select  TIME.CURRENT_YEAR  as  Year1,
     TIME.QUARTER_KEY  as  Quarter_key,
     CONCAT(CONCAT( TIME .MONTH_EN , N' ') , cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as Month__caption_,
                              CONCAT(CONCAT( TIMEQUARTER.QUARTER_EN , N' ') , cast( TIME .CURRENT_YEAR as varchar (4)))  as  Quarter__caption_
    from
        [GOSALESDW]. TIME   TIME ,
        [GOSALESDW]. TIMEQUARTER  TIMEQUARTER
    where
         ( TIME .QUARTER_KEY =  TIMEQUARTER.QUARTER_KEY)
```